# Categorical variable with 132 levels in a prediction problem

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, categorical-data

I am trying to use random forest to make a prediction for price with below data frame

```r
data.frame':    10682 obs. of  9 variables:
 Airline        : Factor w/ 12 levels "Air Asia","Air India",..: 4 2 5 4 4 9 5 5 5 7 ...
 Source         : Factor w/ 5 levels "Banglore","Chennai",..: 1 4 3 4 1 4 1 1 1 3 ...
 Destination    : Factor w/ 6 levels "Banglore","Cochin",..: 6 1 2 1 6 1 6 6 6 2 ...
 Route          : Factor w/ 132 levels "BLR → AMD → DEL",..: 19 88 123 96 30 68 6 6 6 109 ...
 Additional_Info: Factor w/ 10 levels "1 Long layover",..: 8 8 8 8 8 8 6 8 6 8 ...
 Duration_Num   : num  1.04 2 2.94 1.69 1.56 ...
 Total_Stops_Num: num  0 2 2 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 Departure_Num  : POSIXct, format: "2019-03-24 22:20:00" "2019-05-01 05:50:00" ...
 Price          : num  8.27 8.94 9.54 8.74 9.5 ...
```

Initially i tried Multiple linear regression so i log transformed the dependent variable (Price)

All the non numeric variables were character before so i converted them into factor and date time

The variable Route has 132 levels. I tried one hot encode but results were not as good

How to preprocess this variable with 100+ levels as Random forest is getting failed every time

Comment: I've voted to migrate this question to [stats.se], since it is about the theory, not the programming, of the problem.

Comment: Why not calculate distance from start to destination and throw away the Route? (I don't think it's about statistical theory at all but rather about referring to the underlying reality for the problem.)

Comment: Number of stops is already there as a separate variable ->  "Total_Stops_Num". And calculating distance will be very complicated - error prone  i guess as it will vary depending on the route

Comment: Will reducing the levels by combining them using their frequency distribution or response rate work in this scenario ?